# Как в sass сложить значения переменных, заданных в разных единицах измерения?

Tags: вёрстка, переменные, sass, scss, препроцессор

Каким образом можно сложить rem и px c помощью sass. Есть две переменные у одной ширина задана в `px`, а у другой в `rem`. Возможно ли их сложить, не вводя новую переменную? На выходе хочу получить пиксели:

```
$width1: 100px
$width2: 2rem

.container
  width: $width1+$width2
```

Comment: А как программе угадать, что Вы хотите получить на выходе? :)
`rem` или `px`

Comment: @yozhezhi Ну вот может быть есть способ, которым можно задать, что я хочу получить на выходе) Хочу получить 'px'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот такую функцию-хэлпер написать (синтаксис scss):

```
$base-font-size: 16px;
$width1: 100px;
$width2: 2rem;

@function rem-to-px($size) {
  $parseInted: $size / ($size * 0 + 1);
  $value: $parseInted * $base-font-size;
  @return round($value);
}

.container {
  width: $width1 + rem-to-px($width2); // -> 132px
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Подойдет!